# Javascript curried sum function throws an error saying curriedSum is not a function

Tags: javascript, currying

Writing a curried sum function. Why does this throw an error saying curriedSum is not a function when invoked many times in one line? However, if I uncomment the else statement, it works fine. Doesn't the program go into the last identical return-statement when if-condition is not satisfied, and returns the same thing?

```
 function curriedSum(arg){

  let numbers = [];

  
  function summing(nextNum){
    numbers.push(nextNum);

    if(numbers.length === arg){
      return numbers.reduce(function(accum, num){
        return accum+num;
      });
    }
      // else{
     // return summing;
   // }
  }

  return summing;
}





const sum = console.log(curriedSum(3)(2)(1)(7));
```

Comment: it works with the else because the else block returns a function, without it summing returns a number or undefined, neither can be used as a function

Comment: It only goes to a next `return` statement if it's inside the same function scope. In this case, since the `return` is directly inside `curriedSum` instead of directly inside `summing`, it doesn't get called inside `summing`

Comment: Where is `nextNum` defined?

Comment: @zer00ne it's a paramter for `summing`

Comment: @Samathingamajig yes I know what it is, but where is it defined? ex. `const nextNum = anotherFunctionSomewhereElse()`

Comment: @zer00ne your question does not make sense. It's "defined" as a parameter of the function `summing`. It gets its value when `summing` is called. Here, when the `else` block is uncommented, its values are `2`, `1`, and `7` because it's called three times.

Comment: When calling `summing` on return of `curriedSum`, there isn't any value being returned  when it's commented out. It isn't clear at all to the purpose of your code. Please 1. post code as a [mcve] . 2. Give an example of typical input. 3. Give an example of expected result. 4. Show what you actually get as a result instead.